# Having trouble when loading TikZ-cd

Tags: installing, tikz-cd

I have just installed the package `tikz-cd` using the MikTeX package manager, but somehow it won't load properly. I've included the error message. Could anyone help me out?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}% or \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{cd} tried both; same errors.

\begin{document}
 text
\end{document}
```

Error message:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/handlers/first char syntax' an
>   d I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
>
> See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.38 \pgfkeys{/handlers/first char syntax=true}
>
> ?

Comment: Are you sure your packages are up-to-date? I have no such problem. Try uninstalling tikz-cd and reinstall it, just to see. In particular, do you have tikz `3.0`?

Comment: @Bernard I just updated everything and reinstalled tikz-cd. How can I find out what version of `tikz` I have?

Comment: Actually it's the `pgf` package. Launch `MiKTeX Package Manager`, select `pdf` (you can filter by name to go faster), right-click-> Properties. You should see v. 3.0.0 (02/28/2014). Oh! by the way do everything as administrator.

Comment: @Bernard I am a bit confused. It was my understanding that `TikZ` came with the MikTeX distribution. Apparently not. I have now installed `pgf` (I hadn't before). My MWE still doesn't work though. I now have a different error message (see editet version of OP). But my guess is that I screwed up the installation some how...

Comment: Perhaps you should run `MiKTeX Update` both as administrator *and* as user. This might be due to two different versions for pgf.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much. That did it. It took me a bit longer to respond, because I had selected all possible updates, which apparently ment that you need to install `babel-<your language>` since `babel` had an update.

Comment: @Bernard If you would convert you comments into an answer, then I could express my gratitude through upvoting and accepting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably a problem  with outdated  packages versions. The `tikz-cd` package, in its last version (0.9), is built upon `pgf 3.0`. You should use `MiKTeX Updater` to update your installation both as administrator and as user, in order to have full compatibility.