# pgfkeys error while uploading to arXiv, which files to upload?

Tags: pgfkeys, tikz-cd, arxiv

My thesis compiles very well on my and others computers (no errors, no warnings, just some small badboxes around images).

On the other hand, when trying to compile it on arXiv, I get many errors. I was able to solve some of them by manually uploading 
`tikzlibrarycd.code.tex` and `tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex` but now I do not understand how to get around this:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/handlers/first char syntax' an
d I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.38 \pgfkeys{/handlers/first char syntax=true}

? 
! Emergency stop.
... 

l.38 \pgfkeys{/handlers/first char syntax=true}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on thesis.log.
```

(full report [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23435366/))

The only relevant discussion that I found while googling is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208513/61085), but obviously I cannot update anything on their server. So, I contacted them; they are aware of the many problems that they have by using an old distribution (2011), and they are trying to update it, but it takes a long time to maintain retro-compatibility. In the meanwhile, they said to

> 1. Include the complete tikz package for the version you're using locally within your source directory; or
> 2. Compile out your figures into images and embed them in your tex source using any figure inclusion command you choose (such as the \includegraphics directive from graphicx).

I would really like to avoid the second one unless there is an automated way to do it (I have *a lot* of `tikz-cd` figures, some of which are also inline).
So, my question focus on the first "solution". What files do I need to upload *exactly*?

Comment: It means arxiv doesn't have TikZ (pgfkeys in this case) v3.

Comment: I know what it means. The question is not about what it means; it is about what files should I upload exactly to have `tikz-cd` working there.

Comment: @percusse THAT is the solution to option 2 that I was looking for! :D I could not find it with the search, which keywords did you choose?

Comment: `arxiv tikz site:tex.stackexchange.com` on google

Comment: My pleasure, good luck